# How to use bash to split column by strings?

Tags: bash, awk, grep

Given the tab delimited file with eight columns:

```
22  51244237    rs575160859 C   T   100 PASS AC=19;AF=0.00379393;AN=5008;NS=2504;DP=13345;EAS_AF=0;AMR_AF=0.0043;AFR_AF=0;EUR_AF=0.0099;SAS_AF=0.0061;AA=.|||;VT=SNP
```

How can I use bash to create a new tab delimited file from information in the eighth column with the columns: AF; EAS_AF; AMR_AF; AFR_AF; EUR_AF; SAS_AF and the corresponding numeric value?

ie:

```
#AF         EAS_AF   AMR_AF     AFR_AF   EUR_AF     SAS_AF 
0.00379393  0        0.0043     0        0.0099     0.0061
```

I understand I could split the eigth column by ";" (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156919/splitting-a-column-using-awk) and then remove the unwanted text columns and text strings (ie "AF="), but is there a more efficient way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
{
  match($0,/AF[^;]*/)
  af=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  match($0,/EAS_AF[^;]*/)
  eas=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  match($0,/AMR_AF[^;]*/)
  amr=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  match($0,/AFR_AF[^;]*/)
  afr=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  match($0,/EUR_AF[^;]*/)
  eur=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  match($0,/SAS_AF[^;]*/)
  sas=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  VAL=af OFS ac OFS eas OFS amr OFS afr OFS eur OFS sas
  split(VAL,array,"[= ]")
  print array[1],array[4],array[6],array[8],array[10],array[12] ORS array[2],array[5],array[7],array[9],array[11],array[13]
}' Input_file | column -t
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code too here.

```
awk '
{
  match($0,/AF[^;]*/)             ##Using match out of the box awk function for matching AF string till semi colon.
  af=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)    ##creating variable named af whose value is substring of indexes of RSTART to till value of RLENGTH.
  match($0,/EAS_AF[^;]*/)         ##Using match out of the box awk function for matching EAS_AF string till semi colon.
  eas=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)   ##creating variable named eas whose value is substring of indexes of RSTART to till value of RLENGTH.
  match($0,/AMR_AF[^;]*/)         ##Using match out of the box awk function for matching AMR_AF string till semi colon.
  amr=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)   ##creating variable named amr whose value is substring of indexes of RSTART to till value of RLENGTH.
  match($0,/AFR_AF[^;]*/)         ##Using match out of the box awk function for matching AFR_AF string till semi colon.
  afr=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)   ##creating variable named afr whose value is substring of indexes of RSTART to till value of RLENGTH.
  match($0,/EUR_AF[^;]*/)         ##Using match out of the box awk function for matching EUR_AF string till semi colon.
  eur=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)   ##creating variable named eur whose value is substring of indexes of RSTART to till value of RLENGTH.
  match($0,/SAS_AF[^;]*/)         ##Using match out of the box awk function for matching SAS_AF string till semi colon.
  sas=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)   ##creating variable named sas whose value is substring of indexes of RSTART to till value of RLENGTH.
  VAL=af OFS ac OFS eas OFS amr OFS afr OFS eur OFS sas    ##Creating variable VAL whose value is values of all above mentioned variables.
  split(VAL,array,"[= ]")         ##Using split function of awk to split it into array named array with delimiter space OR =.
  print array[1],array[4],array[6],array[8],array[10],array[12] ORS array[2],array[5],array[7],array[9],array[11],array[13]   ##Printing all array values as per OP.
  af=ac=eas=amr=afr=eur=sas=""    ##Nullifying all variables mentioned above.
}' Input_file     | column -t     ##Mentioning Input_file name here and passing awk output to column command to take output in TAB format.
```

Answer (score 0):

Split column by ";"

```
awk -F";" '$1=$1' OFS="\t" file.temp > tmp && mv tmp file.temp
```

Remove unwanted columns (new header: CHROM POS ID REF ALT QUAL FILTER AC AF EAS_AF AMR_AF AFR_AF EUR_AF SAS_AF)

```
awk '{print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $13, $14, $15, $16, $17}' file.temp > tmp && mv tmp file.temp
```

Remove unwanted strings

```
awk '{ gsub("SAS_AF=", "", $14); print }' file.temp > tmp && mv tmp file.temp
awk '{ gsub("EUR_AF=", "", $13); print }' file.temp > tmp && mv tmp file.temp
awk '{ gsub("AFR_AF=", "", $12); print }' file.temp > tmp && mv tmp file.temp
awk '{ gsub("AMR_AF=", "", $11); print }' file.temp > tmp && mv tmp file.temp
awk '{ gsub("EAS_AF=", "", $10); print }' file.temp > tmp && mv tmp file.temp
awk '{ gsub("AF=", "", $9); print }' file.temp > tmp && mv tmp file.temp
awk '{ gsub("AC=", "", $8); print }' file.temp > tmp && mv tmp file.temp
```

Comment: You need NOT to use these many `awk` commands, we could do it in a single one, could you please check once this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53117140/5866580 and let me know then? I had added explanation too for understanding of it.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to really approach this task:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS="\t"
    numFlds = split("AF EAS_AF AMR_AF AFR_AF EUR_AF SAS_AF",fldNames,/ /)
    printf "#"
    for (i=1; i<=numFlds; i++) {
        printf "%s%s", fldNames[i], (i<numFlds ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}
{
    nf = split($8,tmp,/[;=]/)
    for (i=1; i<nf; i+=2) {
        fldName = tmp[i]
        fldVal  = tmp[i+1]
        name2val[fldName] = fldVal
    }
    for (i=1; i<=numFlds; i++) {
        fldName = fldNames[i]
        fldVal  = name2val[fldName]
        printf "%s%s", fldVal, (i<numFlds ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
#AF     EAS_AF  AMR_AF  AFR_AF  EUR_AF  SAS_AF
0.00379393      0       0.0043  0       0.0099  0.0061
```

The alignment in the output only looks off because it's tab-separated as required.